# i want to open a webpage in a frame inside this tkinter menu class

Tags: python, tkinter, web

i am using tkinter i want to open a webpage frame inside this tkinter menu class but i try webwiev,pywebviev,tkinter HTML

```
import os
import win32gui
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import face2emo
class MenuWindow():
def __init__(self, root):
    self.win_dics = {}
    self.choices = []
    self.win_dimen = 0
    win32gui.EnumWindows(self.win_handler, None)

    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    self.win_op_var = tk.StringVar()
    ttk.Label(frame, text="Window to analyse: ").grid(row=1, column=1)
    ttk.OptionMenu(frame, self.win_op_var, *self.choices).grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.win_op_var.trace('w', self.onchange_dropdown)

    frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

def win_handler(self, hwnd, ctx):
    win_text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win_text != '':
        self.win_dics[win_text] = hwnd
        self.choices.append(win_text)

def onchange_dropdown(self, *args):
    self.win_dimen = face2emo.find_windows_dimension_from_hwnd(
        self.win_dics[self.win_op_var.get()]
    )
```

Comment: Assume the error is telling the truth. If it can't find `./models/conv_emotion_map_036.json`, then it can't. Something you've done requires that file.

Comment: but that file is in that folder

Comment: I recommend using `nuitka` package instead of pyinstaller. With pyinstaller, windows can see your application as a virus even though it is not. It can be due to reading and writing to files etc. I personally had those problems and I resolved it with `nuitka`. Maybe try it and see if it will resolve your problem, even though it is not by using package that you desire.

Comment: Maybe it's in the folder, but maybe your current working directory is not in the right place. If python tells you it can't find a file, it literally cannot find the file with the path you've given.

Comment: does nuitka work on windows